# Designing recipe database - should ingredient be a separate table?

Tags: database, database-design

I currently have a recipe and ingredient as separate tables with an association of `ingredients belongs to recipe`

I came across a few different examples of a recipe database and it seems to be common practice to separate out ingredient from recipe. The thing is that I anticipate ingredient inputs to be like

- 2 tbsp of sea salt
- 80g of butter

I believe the conventional design to keep from data redundancy only makes sense when ingredient input has no quantifying measure like

- sea salt
- butter

But when you start mixing quantity with ingredients, every input is likely to become a unique record.

Is it still advised to separate ingredient out of recipe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a `Recipes` table, an `Ingredients` table, a `Measures` table, and a `RecipeIngredients` table, which is a function table.  It would have columns such as:

- RecipeId
- IngredientId
- MeasureId
- Amount

The first three would have foreign key relationships to other tables.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems very modular and scalable.